# Third party dependencies in typescript npm modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I am constructing an npm module in typescript, which when published will contain the generated `.d.ts`, '.js' and '.js.map' files. This module will in turn be dependent on other modules eg. `react`, `react-dom`. Now my question is, when someone installs my module in their app, How do i check whether the installing app is a typescript or javascript project, and if it is a typescript project how do i automatically install the required `typings` dependencies specified in my module's `typings.json`.

If there is something wrong with the approach i am going for here, then any other approach is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

With typings, I would suggest you allow your consumers to manage transitive dependencies on their own. That means if you depend on declaration files through typings, don't bundle any declaration files installed by typings. Instead, just bundle your own `.d.ts` files, and let consumers install declaration files on their own through typings.

If you use TypeScript 2.0 and later, you can instead just use npm and `@types` for your dependencies. [See more about `@types` on the official TypeScript blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

For instance, if you depend on the `react` package, then you should just add `@types/react` to the `dependencies` field in your `package.json`